# Alternative for goto in java

Tags: java, break

In a Thread named a I have 2 loops, they both have to stop when flag is false.
Somthing like that:

```
boolean flag = true;

t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(flag && another_condition)
        {
        }

        Do_something_that_takes_time

        while(flag && another_condition)
        {
        }

    });
}
```

Let's assume that we entered the first loop and in the middle of the loop run changed to false, now we will move to the "Do_somthing..." lane which might take few seconds to complete and then we will be moved to the second loop.
In the meantime the value of flag might be changed once again to true! which means I will execute the second loop and I don't wish for that. So is that possible to do something like:

```
boolean flag = true;

t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(another_condition)
        {
            goto end;
        }

        Do_something_that_takes_time

        while(flag && another_condition)
        {
            goto end;
        }
        end:    
    });
}
```

The code I wrote now of course is not working but it's just to demonstrate my will.
I know "break" should be the solution but I couldn't come up with a solution by using it.

Comment: If you want to break/exit `run` method then just use `return;`

Comment: @Pshemo thanks! post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to break/exit from `run` method then you can just use `return;`.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `while` loops in methods, and after you exit the second loop/method, check if you need to call the first method again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines using `break` and another condition.

```
boolean flag = true;
boolean skip = false;

t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(another_condition)
        {
            skip = true;    
            break;
        }

        if (!skip) Do_something_that_takes_time;

        while(flag && another_condition && !skip)
        {
            break;
        }  
    });
}
```